# Is log(f(n)^c)=Ω(log(g(n))) or not

Tags: algorithm

You are given functions f and g such that f(n)=Ω(g(n)).  Is log(f(n)^c)=Ω(log(g(n)))? (Here c is some positive constant.)  You should assume that f and g are non-decreasing and always bigger than 1.

This a question in my algorithm course and i cant figure out if it's true or false or depending on the constant or depending on the functions f and g

Comment: That's omega in the complexity-lower-bound sense? You don't normally see that with an equals sign, since it's a bound not an equality. (And if this was true then the omegas here would necessarily have different constant factors themselves, which makes the equals sign even more wrong as far as I'm concerned.)

Comment: @Rup That's Omega in the definition of Omega sense. I don't see anything wrong with an equality here. In fact I don't know what else you would write instead of an equality.

Comment: @michelhamad What do you know about logarithm? Do you know some cool formula that would allow you to simplify the expression `log(f(n)^c)`?

Comment: @michelhamad Have you tried to see if this happens to be true or false on a few examples? Can you give me an example of two functions `f` and `g` such that `f(n) = Ω(g(n))`?

Comment: @Stef For the first question yes i know how to simplify it. Its simplification is c*log(f(n)). for the second no i didn't try on an example . here is an example  of two functions f and g such that f(n) = Ω(g(n)) . Ex: 0.5n3 + 100n = Ω(n3)

Comment: @michelhamad Can you please remind me of your definition of Ω( ) and what that would mean in the case `0.5n3 + 100n = Ω(n3)`?

Comment: @Stef Ω( ) definition is 0 <= cg(n)<=f(n) for all n >= n0, on this example it will be true

Comment: @Stef The prof. in the question need a general answer, if it's true or false or depending on the constant or depending on the functions f and g , i think its depending on the g and f but not sure

Comment: @Stef well, because it isn't an equivalence relation. Which is generally what an `=` sign implies, although, it is very common to say `f(n) = O(g(n))`, (or `Ω`) but it would probably be more correct to say something like `f(n) ∈ O(g(n))`, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066004/big-o-notation-is-element-of-or-is-equal

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for the link to this question. The answers actually appear to support the use of `=` rather than the inconvenient `∈`. In particular [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066054/810464) explains clearly why the use of `=` is convenient and not harmful if used properly. And this comment "I would go as far as saying that using [`∈`] almost completely defeats the very purpose of the notation, rendering it pointless to introduce it in the first place. "

Comment: @Stef I tend to disagree, but really, my point was that it isn't exactly uncontested. At the end of the day, though, formalisms are just tools, as long as we all understand what is meant, then it's ok as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward to prove. As `f(n) = Omega(g(n))`, it means `lim{n -> ∞} f(n)/g(n) > 0`.
As `f` and `g` are non-decreasing and greater than 1, and `log` is an increasing function, `lim{n -> ∞} log(f(n))/log(g(n)) > 0`. Hence, `log(f(n)) = Omega(log(g(n))`.

On the other hand `log(f(n)^c) = c log(f(n))`. As `c` is a constant factor, `log(f(n)^c)` is `Omega(log(g(n))` as well anf your claim is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, I point out that instead of this notation `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` I use this `f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))`

---

From Omega definition we have:

`f(n) ∈ g(n) <=> ∃s,k > 0 | f(n) >= s*g(n) ∀n >= k`

So for `log(f(n)^c) ∈ Ω(c*log(g(n)))`  we can say:

1. `∃s > 0 (s=c for easiness) | log(f(n)^c) >= c*log(g(n)) ∀n >= k`

Then we have:

2. `c*log(f(n)) >= c*log(g(n)) ∀n >= k`
3. `f(n) >= g(n) ∀n >= k`

And since we know that `f(n) ∈ Ω(g(n))` we can state that `log(f(n)^c) ∈ Ω(c*log(g(n)))` .